# Using ggplot to create boxplots for all columns in a dataset vs a single dependent variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

Thank you guys so much for your help, I am an R student and working with a dataset concerning breast cancer diagnosis, this data set has a variable that I have renamed as "class" that classifies is a female patients has cancer (1) or not (0), and there are 30 independent numerical variables that will be used to predict if a patient is likely to have cancer or not, I am working on describing the data graphically and what I would like is to create a boxplot for each independent variable versus the variable "class" but I want it in a way that I can have a 6x5 or 5x6 layout with each independent variable versus class and I want the y-axis to adjust for the  scale of each independent  variable

this is the code for the dataset

```
web_db<-read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedy/Machine-Learning-with-R-datasets/master/wisc_bc_data.csv")
web_db$y<-ifelse(web_db$diagnosis=="M",1,0)
web_db<-web_db[,-c(1:2)]
names(web_db)[31] <- "class"
web_db$class<-as.factor(web_db$class)
```

I have tried this piece of code:

```
ggplot(stack(web_db), aes(x = ind, y = values)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

but it does not plot what I want, what I want is something like the following indiviaul plot but in a 6x5 or 5x6 layout with each indepenent variable in each slot.

```
ggplot(web_db,aes(class,radius_mean)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

Thank you so much guys for all the help!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to see something like this ?

[image]

**code;**

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

web_db  %>%
melt(id.vars = 'class') %>%
ggplot(aes(x=class,y=value))+
geom_boxplot(aes(color=class))+
facet_wrap(~variable,scales = "free_y")+
theme(axis.title = element_text(size=2))
```

Comment: Hello Samet thank you for your reply this is something I was looking for! Thank you for your time I have a question why do we need reshape? is there a way to do this without it? and secondly why on the x-axis the "class" isnt allocated over x=1 and x=0?

Comment: @R_Student You can remove them by removing `aes(color=class)` tag. I reshaped data because  ggplot's aes has one x argument and it should represent all variables you wanna show. Then I turned them into parts by `facet_wrap`. Do not forget to approve the answer if it fixes your problem :)

Comment: @R_Student I edited code and plot output again, now x axis shows `class` variable